# Como dar formato de moneda a una consulta de SUM en sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estoy intentando dar formato de moneda a un total de ventas. Individualmente tengo los 2 queries necesarios, pero no se como hacerlos uno.

```
SELECT '$' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, CONVERT(VARCHAR, CAST(12345  AS MONEY), 1))
```

> Este lo encontre en uno de los hilos de Stack Overflow

Me funciona, me devuelve el resultado con el formato de moneda, pero necesito agregerla la suma del total de mi tabla ventas, no un numero al azar. Asi obtengo el total de mi tabla ventas>

```
select sum (Total)  as TotalVentas from Tab_ventasdetalle
```

como puedo hacerlo en un solo query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solo se debe reemplazar el número al azar por `sum(Total)` que sería el número real.

```
SELECT '$' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, CONVERT(VARCHAR, CAST(sum (Total)  AS MONEY), 1))
AS TotalVentas FROM Tab_ventasdetalle
```

Versión simplificada:

```
SELECT '$' + CONVERT(varchar,CAST(sum(Total)  AS MONEY),1)
AS TotalVentas FROM Tab_ventasdetalle
```